# SyntaxError: 'return' outside function error

Tags: python

I don't know what to do for "return data" to be in the function

```
# Use Google_Speech_Recognition
data = ""
try:
    data = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("You said " + data)
except sr.UnknownValueError:  # Check for unknown errors
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand what you said, unknown error")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Request result from Google Speech Recognition service error" + e)

return data
```

**Error**
Output error: return data
^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: There is no function in your code; the error message is correct. Your indentation is also not correct.

Comment: Where is the function? please post the complete code

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return because you have no function

This will avoid your current error:

```
def listen_audio():
    data = ""
    try:
        data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said " + data)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:  # Check for unknown errors
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand what you said,   unknown error")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Request result from Google Speech Recognition service error" + e)
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = listen_audio()
```

Answer (score 1):

The value for data in this code will remain because the variable is out of the try/except suites. You don't need the return operator.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a return statement inside the try block, but you have to place another return outside the try block as well. If you pass true while calling the sayHello method, it would return from the try block. A return statement has to be at the method level instead of at any other specific level.

I hope you got the answer you want